# How to use dp instead of pixels in RecyclerView.ItemDecoration()?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a custom class to use offsets inside my RecyclerView.

```
class SpacesItemDecoration(private var space: Int) : RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {

    override fun getItemOffsets(outRect: Rect, view: View, parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State) {
        super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state)
        outRect.bottom = space
    }
}
```

Then I set the offsets in my code like that:

```
addItemDecoration(SpacesItemDecoration(25))
```

It works, but it sets the offsets in pixels. How am I supposed to use dp instead of pixels? And why Google preferred using pixels here? It already should be deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but no. I know that I can convert them, but it's weird. In different phones it will look a little bit different than it should be.

Comment: That's because when you use dp you should be using `dimen.xml` resource not an hardcoded integer . And you should be having `dimen.xml` for multiple device types.

Comment: "In different phones it will look a little bit different than it should be." then you should include what you mean in your question, as the answer you've accepted just describes how to convert them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by this method you should first convert dp to pixels than set

```
fun Context.dpToPixel(dp: Float): Float {
    return dp * (resources.displayMetrics.densityDpi.toFloat() / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT)
}
```

by this

```
addItemDecoration(SpacesItemDecoration(dpToPixel(25f)))
```